# Nested router-outlet in angular 5.2.0

Tags: angular, nested, angular-routing

I have problem with nesting routes in Angular when it comes to lot of childs.

Here is my RouteConfig:

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [Auth],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'administrator',
        component: AdministratorComponent,
        canActivate: [Role],
        children: [
        {
            path: "users",
            component: UsersComponent,
            children: [
            {path: ':page', component: UsersComponent},
            {
                path: 'preview',
                children: [
                    {path: ':id', component: UsersComponent}
                ]
            },
            {path: 'add', component: UsersEditComponent},
            {
                path: 'edit',
                children: [
                   {path: ':id', component: UsersEditComponent}
                ]
            }
            ]
        },
        {path: "params", component: ParamsComponent}
    ]
}
```

}

The problem shows on routes 
`/administrator/users/add`
`/administrator/users/edit/{id}`
`/administrator/users/preview/{id}`
because of nested router-outlet

My app.component.html

```
<router-outlet (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
```

My AdministratorComponent

```
<div class="col s12">
    <div class="row tab-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the AdministratorComponent I dynamicly load UsersComponent or ParamsComponent, I am interested in UsersComponent in this case, it looks like this:

```
<div class="users-table">    
<!--some code--!>
    <a [routerLink]="['/administrator', 'users', 'add']" routerLinkActive="active">Add</a>
</div>
```

Now what I want to archive is to make this `<a>` element to work in router-outlet from AdministratorComponent, is that possible? If not, how I should refactor that? I need some fresh idea, because I got stuck.
I hope that my question is clear to understand.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your use-case but your routing design is bad. Most of the nested are not needed. Considering flatten the nested routes a bit.

Comment: I agree, rotes without component (only with childs) can be flatten. I did it before I asked the question, but it does not affect the result of functionality.

Comment: Consider moving contents for `../users/:page` and `../users/preview/:id` out to a different component (UsersViewComponent?!). When you have Children set in your `/users` route, the children will be displayed in `router-outlet`. It looks like that Angular won't allow you to have a component to reference itself inside of `router-outlet`.

Comment: uhh, that's what I was affraid of, I did to complicated html, where /users is only a dynamicly loaded tab in /administrator and /preview is a footer-fixed popup, everything on the same view. Anyway, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found out the solution for this example:

1. Remove `component: UsersComponent` from /administrator/users path
2. Add `{path: '', component: UsersComponent}` as a child to /administrator/users
3. Correct order of the routes is:

   a. `''`
   b. `'add'`
   c. `'preview'`
   d. `':page'`

Now routing on nested router-outlet works as I expected.